# os/c-api/il2cpp-config-platforms.h' file not found when build running at ios plateform for using @azesmway/react-native-unity

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, unity-game-engine, github

os/c-api/il2cpp-config-platforms.h' file not found
This error occur when I build the project, using a real device at xocde with ios plateform.

`[enter code here][1]`[os/c-api/il2cpp-config-platforms.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKOJS.png)

I have spend a lot of time to attempt it for last three week & tried manys ways to resolve it but remain until falied so kindly guide me properly that how to resolve it .
but the error is still occurring. Any help?

Also you may look the short video at below for better understanding of this coming issue:
*https://drive.google.com/file/d/18LZpOL3uOZZ5Ae5XkGdaQdQGFjrVZrhC/view?usp=sharing*

I have also cleand properly  with this below command

```
Replace [PRJECT_NAME] with RNUnity
"cd ios; rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods; rm -rf Pods; rm -rf [PROJECT_NAME].xcworkspace; rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*; pod deintegrate; rm -f ios/Podfile.lock; pod setup; arch -x86_64 pod install;”
```

And also I have proper fallowed the documentation of this below defined package with each & everything step by step in more confident way but still remain error.

> @azesmway/react-native-unity

Now Using version

> "@azesmway/react-native-unity": "^1.0.7",    "react": "18.2.0",
> "react-native": “0.72.3”

> -> Environment: Unity - 2020.3.42,  Xcode - Version 15.2 (15C500b)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.